# Open clickable text in emacs in new/neighboring window

Tags: emacs

Currently I have a mode (magit to be precise) when I have [clickable text](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html) switches buffer to the file. However I'd prefer sometimes to open in new or neighboring window. Is it possible to do it?

PS. By Window I mean Emacs window not Emacs frame.

Answer (score 2):

In a `magit-status` buffer you can **usually** achieve this with `C-u RET`.
The same **usually** works for active links in `info-mode` and `help-mode`.

But there's no generic way to do this in Emacs. As the [document you linked to](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Clickable-Text.html) explains, it's left to the major modes' discretion how they respond to actions on clickable text.
The prescription is:

> Implementing a link involves three separate steps: (1) indicating clickability when the mouse moves over the link; (2) making  or Mouse-2 on that link do something; and (3) setting up a follow-link condition so that the link obeys mouse-1-click-follows-link.

This however is not a required protocol:

- Nothing says that it needs to be implemented in full,
- also it is not mandated to always respond with visiting a buffer upon activation,
- neither is it mandated to treat all links in a given buffer the same way;
- hence the "usually" above.

A couple of examples where you can readily observe differences in behavior:

- `magit-status` buffers don't respond to mouse clicks at all, only "keyboard clicks" (`RET`s)
- `info-mode` only provides the "open in new window" behavior for "keyboard clicks" but not for mouse clicks.
- `magit-status` only provides this behavior when visiting files, but not when "visiting" commits. Also "visiting" (keyboard clicking) commits has a side-effect of checking them out first and then displaying them.
- In `describe-function` buffers the links pointing to source files always open new frame, with no option to do otherwise.
- In `describe-function` buffers the links pointing to other functions always load the new contents in the current buffer, with no option to do otherwise.
- In `magit` history buffers and `describe-function`'s `help-mode` buffers the `[back]' and`[forward]` buttons always update the current buffer.
- In `describe-mode` buffers the links to "Enabled minor modes" cross-references just scroll down in the current window.
- `dired-mode` buffers don't highlight active links.

The implementation details of all this is probably pretty intricate but to illustrate there is no real magic there, compare how `info-mode` [treats mouse clicks and keyboard clicks differently](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/info.el?id=1f3e13c15fb34571a510e69c8dfe6c88e292c593#n3831) (compare `defun Info-mouse-follow-nearest-node (click)` and `defun Info-follow-nearest-node (&optional fork)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** On solution would be to install [org-magit](https://github.com/sigma/org-magit) package. then, you could use the following command (from OrgMode) to force your link to be open in a new window

```
Ctrl-u Ctrl-c Ctrl-o
```

---

**To open files and buffers in new window:**

You can open a buffer in a new window with the following command

```
Ctrl-x 4 b
```

Note than you can also open a file in a new window with a similar command

```
Ctrl-x 4 f
```

Comment: Sorry I have not described it clearly. Neither `C-x 4 b` not `C-x 4 f` is what I am looking for. I have an active text 'link' (sorry I don't know emacs-speak for it) like in info page which opens a new buffer with some file or commit or whatever. I want to open this new buffer in new window. I don't seeks how to open a file or an existing file in new window.

Comment: Hopefully my new answer would help you. Sorry for the misunderstanding of your question.

Comment: No. Magit does not depend on org-mode (and it is not standardized unfortunately) so it results in `C--c C-o is undefined`.

Comment: Ok. See my new answer, to be able to use org-mode.